# Javadoc link qualification

Tags: javadoc

I am looking for a build configuration which modifies the default Javadoc link rendering in the following way. Hopefully the answer is flexible to meet the needs of Ant, Maven, and other users who may be looking for the same solution.

For documentation within a class `Foo` containing (or inheriting) a field `bar`, the following Javadoc tags properly resolve to links in the documentation.

- `{@link Foo#bar}` renders as [`Foo.bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification)
- `{@link Foo#bar bar}` renders as [`bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification)
- `{@link #bar}` renders as [`Foo.bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification)
- `{@link #bar Foo.bar}` renders as [`Foo.bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification)

I am instead interested in generating the documentation with link rendering according to the following rules.

- `{@link Foo#bar}` renders as [`Foo.bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification)
- `{@link Foo#bar bar}` renders as [`bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification)
- `{@link #bar}` renders as [`bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification) **← This rule changed**
- `{@link #bar Foo.bar}` renders as [`Foo.bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221403/javadoc-link-qualification)

Comment: Side question: Why did you link it to the post. It confused me for a sec. Won't `href="#"` suffice?

Comment: The markup language doesn't allow `#` as a link target by any of: 1) `[text](#)`, 2) `[text][1]` with `[1]: #` at the end of the post, or 3) `<a href="#">text</a>`.